# What is wrong with my code in sml?

Tags: sml

I don't know why my code doesn't work.

```
fun lookup _ [] = 0
  | lookup key ((k,v)::entries) =
    if k = key
    then v
    else (lookup key entries)
```

That's what happened when I tested it in cmd.

```
val lookup = fn : ''a -> (''a * int) list -> int
- lookup (1,[(1,2),(2,3)]);
val it = fn : ((int * (int * int) list) * int) list -> int
```

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with your code, you just didn't call `lookup` with enough arguments. You make a common mistakes among beginner SML programmers coming from other languages. I'll try to clarify that.

First, the most important thing to know about functions in Standard ML is this:

> **All** functions in Standard ML take exactly one argument.

You might be confused at this point, because your `lookup` function looks as if it's taking two arguments. It kind of does, but not really.

There are two main "workarounds" (I'm using quotes because this is actually a great feature of the language) for representing functions that take multiple arguments:

### 1. Using curried functions

If you need to write a function which, conceptually, needs three arguments, then you'd write this:

```
fun quux a =
  fn b =>
    fn c =>
      (* do something with a, b and c *)
```

So, `quux` is:

- a function, which takes an argument `a` and returns
- a function, which takes an argument `b` and returns
- a function, which takes an argument `c` and returns
- the result computed using `a`, `b` and `c`

How would you call `quux`? Like this, right?

```
((quux a) b) c
```

But function application is already left associative, so we can actually write this:

```
quux a b c
```

We don't need parentheses to "call" functions! In Standard ML parentheses don't mean "call this function". They're used just for grouping expressions together when you want to change associativity, like in mathematics: `(1 + 2) * 3`.

Because defining `quux` as above is really cumbersome, there's a syntactic shortcut in the language. Instead of writing this:

```
fun quux a =
  fn b =>
    fn c =>
      (* do something with a, b and c *)
```

We can write just this:

```
fun quux a b c = (* do something with a, b and c *)
```

But, they're the same thing. `quux` is still a function which takes just argument `a` and returns a new function with argument `b`, which returns a new function which argument `c`.

Ok, so that was one way of representing multi-argument functions in Standard ML. It's also the one you used to define `lookup`.

### 2. Using tuples

Another common way of representing multi-argument functions is to accept a tuple (which may have from 2 to as many components as you wish). Here's the above example using a tuple now:

```
fun quux args =
  case args of
    (a,b,c) => (* do something with a, b and c *)
```

How could we call `quux` now? Like this:

```
quux (a,b,c)
```

Notice that I put a space between `quux` and the tuple. It's optional, but I do it all the time to keep remembering that function application in standard ML is *not* represented by parentheses. `quux` gets called because it's been put before the tuple `(a,b,c)`. Tuples, however, do require parentheses, which is why you're seeing them above.

Again, as before, it's cumbersome to define `quux` like this:

```
fun quux args =
  case args of
    (a,b,c) => (* do something with a, b and c *)
```

So we can actually use another great feature of the language, pattern matching in argument position, that lets us write this:

```
fun quux (a,b,c) = (* do something with a, b and c *)
```

Ok, now we can really answer your question.

---

You defined `lookup` using the curried function syntax:

```
fun lookup _ [] = 0
```

But you "called" `lookup` using the tuple syntax, where `1` is the first element of the tuple and `[(1,2),(2,3)]` is the second element.

```
lookup (1, [(1,2),(2,3)])
```

Why doesn't the compiler complain, though. In this unfortunate case, it doesn't because it happens that the type of the first argument of lookup is a tuple. So, you've basically called `lookup` with a single argument.

What you wanted was this:

```
lookup 1 [(1,2),(2,3)]
```

Notice that I'm not defining a tuple anymore.