# Standard ML: Unsure of Type of Higher Order Function

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm reading Harper's book, Intro to Standard ML, and am a bit confused on section 11.3, Returning Functions.

1) He defines a function that creates constant functions.  He writes:

"Given a value k, the application `constantly k` yields a function that yields `k` whenever it is applied.  Here's a definition of `constantly`:

```
val constantly = fn k => (fn a => k)
```

The function constantly has type `'a -> ('b -> 'a)`."  This makes sense to me: you supply a value of type 'a and it returns a function that always returns that value (of type 'a), regardless of the input (of type 'b, which may or may not be same as type 'a).

But then he says we can also define this function as:

```
fun constantly k a = k
```

This just looks like a function that takes two arguments and returns the first...but not a function that returns another function...

What am I missing?

2) A little later, Harper discusses a map function.  I understand the basic map function.  He then talks about a map function that will let us apply the passed-in function to many lists (instead of calling our original map function several times with the same passed-in function for each call).  He writes:

```
fun map' f nil = nil
    | map' f (h::t) = (f h) :: (map' f t)
```

"The function map so defined has type `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`.  It takes a function of type 'a -> 'b as argument and yields another function of type `'a list -> 'b list` as result."

I'm pretty lost here as it looks like map' just applies f to all of the elements in a list and returns the resulting list.  So I would have thought it would be of type:

```
('a -> 'b) * 'a list -> 'b list
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: Check out this answer of mine and see if it helps you find the reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29091328/what-is-wrong-with-my-code-in-sml/29094677#29094677 If not, let me know, and I'll try to answer here as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your questions arise from a lack of clarity about what arguments to a function actually are.  In SML, every function (recall that functions are values) takes precisely one argument.  That argument may be a tuple (of type `'a * 'b` but it is still a single argument (that needs to be destructured).

In SML, `fun f x1 x2 ... = T` is syntactic sugar for `val rec f = fn x1 => fn x2 => ... => T`.  So `constantly k` evaluates to `fn a => k`.

Whether you give map the type `('a -> 'b) * 'a list -> 'b list` or `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list` is a library design issue, but the effect is the same.  They do the same thing, though the first takes a tuple of a function and a list, while the second takes the function first and returns a function from lists to lists.  This is called "currying" in the programming languages literature.  (The tuple version is "uncurried", the other is "curried".)

Comment: Hmm if we give the map the first type, don't both arguments need to be in a tuple (which is typically homogenous) within parentheses? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, in the first form you'd pass the arguments as a tuple of a function and a list, e.g. `map (fn x => x + 1, [1,2,3])` which would look weird to functional programmers who expect the curried form (SML, Haskell), but not to others (Lisp, Python).

Answer (score 5):

The magic word is "currying": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

In ML (as well as Haskell) function application binds tighter than any other operator. Thus `constantly k a` parses as `(constantly k) a`. `constantly k` binds to a function. To understand what function, you can mentally think of the definition

```
fun constantly k a = k
```

as being equivalent to

```
fun (constantly k) a = k
```

This says that `(constantly k)` is the function that maps any a to k.

Thus its type is `'a -> ('b -> 'a)`, as claimed in the text.

There is nothing illegal about defining `constantly` via

```
fun constantly (k,a) = k
```

It will have the type `'a * 'b -> 'a` which you seem to expect, but calling it "constantly" then is a bit weird since it wouldn't be a constant function.

I'm sure that Harper will get to it sooner or later. Such functions are heavily used in both ML and Haskell (especially Haskell).

Comment: But this is just a function definition, correct?  constantly doesn't return a function, right?

Comment: The *second* definition isn't of a higher order function (so it doesn't return a function) but the original definition was.